# Fill Entity with data from a separate Entity without a relation in Symfony2 with Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

My webapp has the following: 
ProductsEntity which can have parts that are stored in the PartsEntity, but each Part has it's own value..

Like: Product can have a Part "Length", and that length is different for each Product, so I want to store that in the ProductPartValue table.

For each Product, I want to show all the Parts that are stored in the Parts table. And that you can add to each Part for the Product a Value.

But how do I achieve that in Symfony2, with help of Doctrine?

It is a ManyToMany relation of course (or am I even wrong with that?). All done with Annotations for Doctrine. But I can't get all info the right way, without ugly hacking the code. Any tips? So that I can fill in when editing a Product the Values in the fields list that is based on the PartsTable?

CODE:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ProductPartValue
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Part", inversedBy="parts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="part_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $part;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $value;
}


class Parts
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    public $name;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductPartValue" , mappedBy="parts" , cascade={"all"})
     * */
    protected $parts;
}


class Products
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="info", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $info;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductPartValue", mappedBy="products",  cascade={"all"})
     */
    protected $productsvalues;
}
```

For the Product Form Type I have this:

```
$builder->add('productPartValue','collection', array(
                'type' => new \xx\TheBundle\Form\productPartValueType(), 
                'allow_add' => false, 
                'by_reference' => false
        ));

$builder->add('parts','entity', array(
    'class' => 'xxTheBundle:Parts',
    'property' => 'name',
));
```

But then there is only a select box shown with the Parts, but not a possibility to add values to it. See image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBTL4.png

With help of copndz I added this, but then there is the notice "Undefined variable: productPartValue" in getParts():

```
<?php


    ////// PRODUCT TYPE ///////

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductPartValue", mappedBy="specification",  cascade={"all"})
     */
    protected $productPartValue;


    /**
     * Add productPartValue
     */
    public function addProductPartValue(\The\Bundle\Entity\ProductPartValue $productPartValue)
    {
        $this->productPartValue[] = $productPartValue;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove productPartValue
     */
    public function removeProductPartValue(\The\Bundle\Entity\ProductPartValue $productPartValue)
    {
        $this->productPartValue->removeElement($productPartValue);
    }

    /**
     * Get productPartValue
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getProductPartValue()
    {
        return $this->productPartValue;
    }



    public function getParts() 
    { 
        $parts = new ArrayCollection(); 
        foreach($productPartValue as $part){ 
            $parts = $part->getPart(); 
        } 

        return $parts; 
    }
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [doc about form collections](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) will help you a lot!

Create a ProductType:

```
$formBuilder->add('productValues','collection');
```

Create a ProductPartValueType:

```
$formBuilder->add('part','entity')
            ->add('value')
```

Comment: True. But then it's more to get all Parts listed for Products, but then I'm missing the part where you can add a value for the ProductPartValue.

Comment: Yea ok, true. But still.. Then the 'ProductValues' is not shown. It only gives a selectbox of the Entity of Part. What I want is a list of all my Parts that are in the database. And when there is a Product, I want to show that list of Parts, and be able to add a value in a input field. And the ProductPartValue will be stored in the database, with a FK to the Part and Specification.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the 'value' field... But now, you can edit the collection of productValues in the form and maybe add some by playing with option like allow_add. I'm not sure you can display all parts with their value.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I edited the startpost also few minutes ago. What I want is to display all images. Thats the part I get stuck.

Comment: You are supposed to create two different Type, one for the product, and one for the productPartValue. The product form points to a collectino of productPartValue entities. The productPartValue form points to a couple : choice (select box) of part entity, and a value associated to it. You won't be able to display all parts at the same time, but you'll be able to add one at a time, and then associate them a value.

Comment: Ok, that is something I can get to work, but I really need a full list of parts at the same time. Any ideas how it maybe could work?

Comment: You can display all Part by creating (in your product entity) a getParts() { $parts = new ArrayCollection(); foreach($productValues as $productValue) { $parts = $productValue->getPart(); } return $parts } And then $formBuilder->add('parts', entity, array('multiple'=>true, 'expanded'=>true) in your ProductType. Then you have to create the remove as well and add the cascade persist and remove attribute on $productValue. That may be a start if you want no compromise, but there might be a lot of work to do.

Comment: Updated startpost, implemented your tip @copndz

Comment: Got it! It shows all parts now, but still it's hard to get a input field for each Product, where I can fill in a value, that will store the FK of the Product and Part with the value to ProductPartValue entity.

Comment: I don't know how you can achieve this. Maybe doing templates & stuff. But if I were you I would use the 'collection' type. That wouldn't allow you to display all your entities, with input field, but that would allow you to display all your entities that actually are linked, and a button to add a new relation with a new value.